# Facebook graph event date time for users acceptance

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime, facebook-events

I'm trying to find a way to get the order in which people decided to attend some Facebook events, using Graph.
I can see who is attending the event, who declined, who "maybe", but I didn't find a way to get the date time when people accepted or declined the invite.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I could see a downgrade in the evaluation of my question. Does this mean that there is a simple way to solve it which I didn't find ?

Having a look here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/, I found that event_member contains a date time, which is the one of the event, not of the relation between event and user.
This is what I'm interested in, finding when the user accepted the invite.

Thanks for your comments ;-)

Cédric